# How can I prove that elem z (xs ++ ys) == elem z xs || elem z ys?

Tags: haskell, proof, induction

I have the following:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _ [] = False
elem x (y:ys) = x == y || elem x ys
```

How can I prove that for all x's y's and z's...

```
elem z (xs ++ ys) == elem z xs || elem z ys
```

I attempted to make the left side equivalent to the right side, however none of my attempts have been fruitful.

```
L.S elem z (x:xs ++ y:ys) = z==x || z==y || elem xs || elem ys

R.S elem z (x:xs) || elem z (y:ys) = z==x || z==y || elem xs || elem ys
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is this homework? Edit your question and add whatever sketch of a proof you've come up with so far.

Comment: @Jubobs its a textbook question without a solution, ill post one of my attempts in a minute

Comment: Ok. A tip: prove it by induction on list `xs`. Out of curiosity, which textbook is this from?

Comment: Okay I posted my attempt

Comment: Since you've accepted my answer, I guess you figured out the inductive case by yourself. Right?

Comment: @Jubobs not quite, but I found the base case part really useful, I'm still trying to solve the inductive step

Comment: I'll add some hints for the inductive case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equational reasoning is fun! You'll get the knack of it pretty quickly, if you do a few proofs yourself. I warmly recommend ch. 13 of Graham Hutton's *Programming in Haskell* for a concise introduction.

Anyway, you can prove that, for all equatable and *finite* (see [Tom Ellis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887165/2541573))  `xs`, `ys` and `z`,

```
elem z (xs ++ ys) == elem z xs || elem z ys
```

by induction on list `xs`. For that, you need to use the definitions of `++`, `||`, and `elem`, and use the fact that `||` is associative:

```
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)

False || b = b
True  || _ = True

elem _ [] = False
elem x (y:ys) = x == y || elem x ys
```

#### Base case

Let `ys` be a value of type `Eq a => [a]`, and `z` a value of type `Eq a => a`; then we have

```
elem z ([] ++ ys)
=     {applying ++}
elem z ys
=     {unapplying ||}
False || elem z ys
=     {unapplying elem}
elem z [] || elem z ys
```

#### Inductive case

Let `xs`, `ys` be values of type `Eq a => [a]`, and `x`, `z` values of type `Eq a => a`. Assume (induction hypothesis) that

```
elem z (xs ++ ys) == elem z xs || elem z ys
```

Then we have

```
elem z ((x:xs) ++ ys)
=     {applying ++)
elem z (x : (xs ++ ys))
=     {applying elem}
z == x || elem (xs ++ ys)
=     {induction hypothesis}
z == x || (elem z xs || elem z ys)
=     {associativity of ||}
(z == x || elem z xs) || elem z ys
=     {unapplying elem}
elem z (x:xs) || elem z ys
```

(QED)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hint.

The `++` operator is defined by induction over the *first* argument:

```
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

You want to prove

```
elem z (xs ++ ys) == elem z xs || elem z ys
```

which is a property of `z`, `xs` and `ys`. Let's call it `p(z,xs,ys)`.
Moreover, the first argument of `++` is `xs`, so this suggests to proceed by induction on `xs`.

We need to prove:

1. base case: `p(z,[],ys)`.
2. inductive case: `p(z,x:xs,ys)` assuming the induction hypothesis `p(z,xs,ys)`

You will also need to exploit the definition of `elem` at some point.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on accepted answer, this equation is also true when `xs` is infinite. If `elem z xs = True`, then `elem z (xs ++ ys) = True = elem z xs || elem z ys`. Otherwise, `elem z (xs ++ ys) = ⊥ = elem z xs || elem z ys`, which can be easily verified in ghci.

Comment: "easily verified in ghci" is an overstatement: you can not really check if a program diverges on an infinite list by just running it.  I do concede that, in practice, if such a simple example does not halt in a few seconds, I'd be inclined to believe that it will never halt.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Haskell do not satisfy the principle of induction because Haskell is a lazy language and lists may be infinite.  Instead I believe you should just write two expressions in the same form to show that they are equivalent.  The desired form is

```
f [] = z
f (x:xs) = g x (f xs)
```

To use this approach to prove the desired result take

```
f xs = elem z (xs ++ ys)
f' xs = elem z xs || elem z ys
```

Note that by pattern matching on `xs` and using the definitions of `(++)` and `elem` these are equivalent to

```
f [] = elem z ys
f (x:xs) = x == z || elem z (xs ++ ys)

f' [] = elem z ys
f' (x:xs) = x == z || elem z xs || elem z ys
```

We can rewrite the recursive calls as

```
f [] = elem z ys
f (x:xs) = x == z || f xs

f' [] = elem z ys
f' (x:xs) = x == z || f' xs
```

If we define `g x rest = x == z || rest` then

```
f [] = elem z ys
f (x:xs) = g x (f xs)

f' [] = elem z ys
f' (x:xs) = g x (f' xs)
```

and then note that the expressions for `f` and `f'` are equal.

My previous answer was incorrect:

<del>It's not true.  Consider

    xs = repeat 0
    ys = [1]
    z  = 1

Then

    elem z ys = elem 1 [1] = True

so

    elem z xs || elem z ys = True

but

    elem z (xs ++ ys) = elem 1 (repeat 0 ++ [1]) = False

because the search for `1` in `repeat 0` never terminates.

This is an archetypal example of why the equational theory for lazy languages is less rich than for  strict languages.

As suggested by the other answers you can prove your theorem for *finite* `xs` by structural induction.  But that's somewhat begging the question.  What's a *finite* list?</del>

Comment: You write *the search for `1` in `[0..]` never terminates*, but because `1` is an element of `[0...]` and `||` is lazy in its second argument, it *does* terminate. Did you mean `[0,-1..]` instead?

Comment: I disagree. `elem 1 (repeat 0) || elem 1 [1]` is bottom, not `True`. Similarly, `elem 1 (repeat 0 ++ [1])` is bottom, not `False`. So this is not a counterexample to the claim. See also @user4640123's answer.